# Как преобразовать строку в дату?

Tags: python

Есть строка text = "20170505151338", а на выходе хочу получить 2017-05-05 15:13:38

Использую библиотеку datetime, но у меня получается.

Comment: regex'ом  `(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})` в `\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6`

Comment: `date_str = f"{text[:4]}-{text[4:6]}-{text[6:8]} {text[8:10]}:{text[10:12]}:{text[12:]}"`

Comment: `date_str = "".join(map("".join,zip(map("".join, zip(text[::2], text[1::2])), ("","-","-"," ",":",":",""))))`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Использую библиотеку datetime, но у меня получается.

Если вы имели ввиду **не получается** с помощью `datetime`, то вариант решения:

```
import datetime

text = "20170505151338"

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(text, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

print(date)
```

Если вам необходимо **без `datetime`**:

```
text = "20170505151338"

date = (text[:4] + '-' + text[4:6] + '-' +
        text[6:8] + ' ' + text[8:10] +
        ':' + text[10:12] + ':' + text[12:])

print(date)
```

Comment: Спасибо,видимо я дурачок или что,но я писал '%Y%m%d %H%M%S' именно с пробелом и мне выдавало ошибку..

Comment: @UtKA с кем не бывает, главное разобрались.